# any help? new to android studio

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\devflut\projects\first_app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you add some code that causes this exception, so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Try changing the file permisssions to that gradle folder and granting them for your user.